# How to create a list of objects from with values from another list of values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of objects that hold a list themselves. I'm creating this from another list of elements.

```
class Test():
    temp_list = list()


x = [['a','b','c'],['g','f','h']]

list_of_obj = list()

for i in x:
    test = Test()
    for b in i:
        test.temp_list.append(b)
    list_of_obj.append(test)

for obj in list_of_obj:
    print(obj)
```

The idea in the above code is to split the list of lists (x) into 2 objects that hold all their elements.

However, when I print the temp_list in the objects, both lists have all the elements in x.

OUTPUT

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'f', 'h']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'f', 'h']
```

Expected Output

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['g', 'f', 'h']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `temp_list` is a class attribute.  Class attributes are not unique to instances of the class . They are universal to all instances.

What you want to do is create and instance attribute for `temp_list`  Like this:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.temp_list = []
...
```

Per Random Davis suggestion in the comments:
If you want to be able to print the class directly you should also add this method to your class.

```
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.temp_list)
```

Comment: Also `print(obj)` will just output something like `<__main__.Test object at 0x00000272DF29ED90>`; got to either define `__str__ ` for `Test` or do `print(obj.temp_list)`

Comment: @RandomDavis  I added it in just for you :)